# Can't pass data from one fragment to another through bundle in setGraph of navController

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am going to pass data between fragments; I'm doing this by using bundle and putting it in a setGraph argument, but I can't get it in another fragment and it always returns null. what is the problem?

**Fragment Navigation**

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("deviceSerialNo", "abc");
Log.d("TAGTAG", "onClick: " + bundle);
navController.setGraph(R.navigation.nav_graph, bundle);
navController.navigate(R.id.action_FirstFragment_to_SecondFragment);
```

**Second Fragment**

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(
            LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState
    ) {

        Log.d("TAGTAG", "onCreateView: " + getArguments());
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            String string = getArguments().getString("deviceSerialNo");
        }


        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_second, container, false);
    }
```

Comment: Hi @altruistic, why can't you just use the shared view model to pass the data?

Comment: @ArunPM Hi Arun, I didn't do it before and should try it somewhere :). but I willing to know why this can't work though I think all the things are ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [`setGraph()` documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/NavController#setGraph(int,%20android.os.Bundle)), the `Bundle` you pass in is called `startDestinationArgs`:

> `startDestinationArgs`: arguments to send to the start destination of the graph

So the only reason to use the `setGraph` that takes a `Bundle` is if your `FirstFragment` needs to receive a `bundle` for arguments. You'd need to manually pass those arguments to any other fragment, such as `SecondFragment`, as part of the `navigate()` call.

```
// Pass the arguments to the SecondFragment
navController.navigate(R.id.action_FirstFragment_to_SecondFragment, bundle);
```

Comment: Thanks; how can I pass data to the end destination without committing fragment and just by using Nav Controller?

Comment: That's what `navigate()` does. It doesn't seem like you should be using `setGraph` at all for what you're trying to do.